# Webpack-issue (nodeExternals)

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I m facing the following problem on webpack :

1 --------------------

**webpack.config.js** :

```
{
//...
target: "async-node",
externalsPresets: { node: true },  
externals: [nodeExternals(),],  
//...
}
```

Once the application is launched, I get the following message in my browser console :

```
jsx-runtime":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at react/jsx-runtime (jsx-runtime":1:1)
```

Because react/jsx-runtime uses a require (!= import syntax )

2 --------------------

But if I delete the above-mentioned lines in **webpack.config.js** then I get multiple errors such as :

- Uncaught TypeError: (0 , [...]_*WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE*${num} __. [...]) is not a function [ in browser console ] (during run dev )
- export 'useForm' (imported as 'useForm') was not found in  "react-hook-form" [in terminal console ] (during  build )

---

The minimal code to reproduce the error  :

> https://github.com/Julien280/issueWebPack/tree/main

1. npm run build
2. npm run dev

(btw , I used `npx create-react-app ${appName} --template typescript` to init the app  )

I try to restore project to commonjs (import syntax es6 --> const ... require syntax commonjs ) but that's not really possible as I use es6 features extensively